# Python, WSGI y SSE

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear un servidor WSGI con Python para enviar datos a los clientes web que se conecten mediante el objeto EventSource nativo de Javascript. El servidor funciona perfectamente cuando se conecta el primer cliente, Pero cuando un segundo o tercer cliente se conecta, no recibe ningun tipo de respuesta por parte de SSE (el evento onmessage en el cliente no se ejecuta nunca y lo más raro es que en los logs de la consola del navegador no aparece ningún error al conectarse). Además, cuando ese primer cliente conectado satisfactoriamente recarga la página, el onmessage tarda al ejecutarse en su primer intento (parece que es la función `sleep` la responsable, porque cuando cambio el valor de los segundos, el retraso también cambia en funcion del nuevo valor).

Aquí está lo que he intentado hacer (este es el codigo de lado del servidor lo más resumido posible):

```
from time import sleep

def Root (Environ, start_response):
    start_response ('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream'), ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')])
    while True:
        yield f"data:{ 'Datos de prueba' }\n\n".encode ()
        sleep (1)


from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
with make_server ('0.0.0.0', 8000, Root) as ServidorWSGI: ServidorWSGI.serve_forever ()
```

**NOTAS**:

No quiero usar nada que tenga que ver con frameworks (Django, Flask, etc), aunque si acepto usar alguna pequeña libreria no nativa de Python (como asyncio --- se me ocurre que el problema pudiera estar relacionado con el código síncrono).

Se que el `*` para `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` es una mala idea. Solo lo puse para no abrumar el código con configuraciones innecesarias.

Comment: Asyncio es nativo de Python. Es altamente recomendables que lo estudies si quieres trabajar con comunicaciones. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: He estado probando asyncio para hacwr mi wsgi asíncrono y que no se bloquee, pero no puedo conseguirlo. Puedes echarme una mano?

Comment: Siempre puedes plantear una pregunta sobre un problema concreto que involucre asyncio.

Comment: Es bueno saber eso. Pues este es precisamente mi problema. El codigo adjunto a la pregunta sirve para comunicarse con el frontend por SSE. Si un primer cliente se conecta funciona perfecto (envia los datos del yield cada 1 segundo), pero no funciona para otros clientes. Lo mas probable es q tenga que ver con programación asincrona.